# Is there a way to solve the constrained optimisation function (Lagrange) with n number of constraints?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the constrained optimisation function using Lagrange multipliers.

The function contains two unknown variables: x,y whose values are to be found.

Here is my working code:

```
x, y, lamb = sp.symbols('x, y, lamb', real=True)
func = sp.sqrt((x - tax_amount20) ** 2 + (y - tax_amount10) ** 2)  # Target function
const = (tax20 + 1)* x / tax20 + (tax10 +1) * y / tax10 - total  # Constraint function 

# define lagrangian
lagrang = func - lamb * const

# gradient of Lagrangian
grad_lagrang = [sp.diff(lagrang, var) for var in [x, y, lamb]]

# solving
spoints = sp.solve(grad_lagrang, [x, y, lamb], dict=True)
```

Can anyone advise how to dynamically build the function with n - number of targets and constraints?

**For example**

x,y,z would have:

**1) target function**

```
sp.sqrt((x - tax_amount20) ** 2 + (y - tax_amount10) ** 2 + (z - tax_amount15) ** 2)
```

**2) constraint function**

```
(tax20 + 1)* x / tax20 + (tax10 +1) * y / tax10 + (tax15 +1) * z / tax15 - total
```

Target and constraint functions should therefore be built dynamically depending on how many variables are available.

BTW. we always know the other variables of the function (i.e. **tax20** and **tax_amount20** for **x** ; **tax10** and **tax_amount10** for **y** and so on...)

Comment: Do you try to implement it, or can you use a library with a solver?

Comment: @Roim I need to implement it. I solve it now with sympy.